# Convert special character (<,>,&) of C# string to XML using xElement

Tags: c#, xml, special-characters

C#

```
noticia.Add(new XElement("Imagem", <BR>));
```

i need :

```
<Imagem><BR></Imagem>
```

and not:

```
<Imagem>&lt;BR&gt;</Imagem>
```

thanks all

Comment: But `<Imagem><BR></Imagem>` is not a valid xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this

```
noticia.Add(new XElement("Imagem", new XElement("BR")));
```

However that will give you an extra `/` which you NEED or it's not valid XML.

```
<Imagem><BR/></Imagem>
```

The other options is using CDATA

```
noticia.Add(new XElement("Imagem", new XCData("<BR>")));
```

Which will get you

```
<Imagem><![CDATA[<BR>]]></Imagem>
```

Just generating `<Imagem><BR></Imagem>` is impossible as it's not valid xml.

**EDIT**: If you have the string with other text, in a variable, your only option is CDATA, like this

```
var OutClass = "xpto. <BR>";
noticia.Add(new XElement("Imagem", new XCData(OutClass)));
```

Which results in

```
<Imagem><![CDATA[xpto. <BR>]]></Imagem>
```

Comment: I, thanks you for your answer, but i have a little bigger problem, because i use a string from another class:

Comment: I realy use classes:

I recive from on class the string:

    string OutClass = "xpto. <BR>";

and i use the `XElement()` in another class.

Comment: Can you modify your original question to provide more info about your code, so we can provide a usable answer?

Comment: thanks again, i think that the terminal who reads the XML forgets the <![CDATA[

Comment: @user1774725, so then my edit works for you?  If so, mark this as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that CData only makes your &lt;BR&gt; look like <BR> while internally it is still &lt;BR&gt; so don't be surprised that when trying to process your <![CDATA[<BR>]]> you will get &lt;BR&gt;. Linq to Xml my unescape this for you (I am not sure)

Comment: @Pawel, really? It shouldn't. Or at least, it didn't when I tested it.

Comment: As I said - Linq to Xml may convert it for you but in general CDATA is kind just for convenience - e.g. if you use xslt you will not even know whether a textnode contained CDATA or not.

Comment: @Pawel, I don't understand what you're saying.  It's saved as `<![CDATA[<BR>]]>`.  It doesn't escape the content in CDATA, that's the whole point of CDATA.

Comment: I am trying to say that <![CDATA[<BR>]]> and &lt;BR&gt; is the same thing (in this sense CDATA is just for convenience) you can see it when you run this: Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Parse("<root><![CDATA[<BR>]]>&lt;BR&gt;</root>").Root.Value); Here is the result: <BR><BR>. If you try processing your Xml with Xslt you won't be able to tell whether in the original document the text node had CDATA section or not.

Comment: Ok, so you unaccepted, but no comment as to WHY this doesn't work...how can we help if you don't provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

I realy use classes:

I recive from on class the string:

```
string OutClass = "xpto. <BR>";
```

and i use the `XElement()` in another class.